# Codeception не хочет работать

Tags: php, apache, юнит-тесты

Не могу понять в чем проблема , установил Codeception глобально.

сам codeception лежит в папке /home/mypc/

настроил его конфиг acceptance.suite.yml и прописал в url адрес веб сервера
127.0.0.1

Вот содержимое самого теста

```
<?php 
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');
$I->amOnPage('/test.html');
$I->see('hello');
```

Вот что выводит Тест

```
1) Welcome2Cept: Perform actions and see result
 Test  tests/acceptance/Welcome2Cept.php
 Step  See "hello"
 Fail  Failed asserting that  on page 127.0.0.1/test.html
-->  404 Not Found Not Found The requested URL /127.0.0.1/test.html was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 80 
--> contains "hello".

Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->see("hello") at tests/acceptance/Welcome2Cept.php:5
 1. $I->amOnPage("/test.html") at tests/acceptance/Welcome2Cept.php:4


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

не могу разобраться в проблеме , может кто уже сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему
нужно было указать порт 80 в конфиге

вот конфиг

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/'
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```